# How to exclude some enum values in System.CommandLine?

Tags: c#, .net, system.commandline

I have a System.CommandLine option like this (LogLevel is an enum):

```
    private static readonly Option<LogLevel> option = new(new[] { "--logLevel" })
    {
        Description = "The severity (log level)."
    };
```

The automatically generated help lists all the enum values as valid values for "--logLevel":

> <Debug|Detailed|Error|Fatal|Info|Off|Silent|Warning>

But is it somehow possible to disallow some of them with System.CommandLine or even map strings on enum values (e.g. "W" is mapped to the enum value Warning)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer in the [Microsoft documentations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/commandline/customize-help):

It works like this:

```
var parser = new CommandLineBuilder(rootCommand)
        .UseDefaults()
        .UseHelp(ctx =>
        {
            ctx.HelpBuilder.CustomizeSymbol(foregroundColorOption,
                firstColumnText: "--color <Black, White, Red, or Yellow>",
                secondColumnText: "Specifies the foreground color. " +
                    "Choose a color that provides enough contrast " +
                    "with the background color. " +
                    "For example, a yellow foreground can't be read " +
                    "against a light mode background.");
        })
        .Build();

await parser.InvokeAsync(args);
```

`foregroundColorOption` is in this case the option and via `firstColumnText`, we can print whatever values of the enum we want to print.